# Is the Mathematica code font available somewhere?

Tags: documentation, fonts

I'm running *Mathematica* 9, which is quite an old version. I often use the specially-formatted double brackets to easily distinguish single and double brackets.  For example, I use:

[image: easy]

instead of:

[image: hard]

which is harder to read.

The double brackets shown in the first example are typically generated using the keys <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> in *Mathematica*. (I think, but am not sure, that much later versions of *Mathematica*, like latter releases of 12 and all releases of 13, automatically format double brackets in that way.)

I am attempting to make course materials that reference *Mathematica*, and I would like to typeset *Mathematica* code (including the specially-formatted double brackets) in word processing software such as Microsoft Word and LaTeX. ***Is it possible to use the *Mathematica* code font in word processors?***

I notice that I have a number of *Mathematica* fonts on my computer:

```
Mathematica1
Mathematica1Mono
Mathematica2
Mathematica2Mono
Mathematica3
Mathematica3Mono
Mathematica4
Mathematica4Mono
Mathematica5
Mathematica5Mono
Mathematica6
Mathematica6Mono
Mathematica7
Mathematica7Mono
```

But they all appear to be fonts for *Mathematica* front end text, not code.  Is the font for *Mathematica* **code** available somewhere?

Comment: I would not advice you to use Word for anything :)  For Latex, see [fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex)  You can also use the listing Latex package and general HTML from it using tex4ht.